# predefined variable in tasks.json which returns GUID

Tags: random, visual-studio-code, guid, vscode-tasks

As a prebuild task, I would like to backup the output file produced by program in earlier debug session. I was thinking if vscode has a predefined variable which creates random string (or guid) to use as filename (or prefix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) v1.8.0 is a command that you can use to create a UUID v4 for use in Tasks, Launch and the editor.

For your `tasks.json` use the following variable

```
${command:extension.commandvariable.UUID}
```

See the extension page if you need it in  the editor or in a keybinding